# Spek - Variable not initialized in test

Tags: kotlin, spek

The following code does not compile:

```
  describe("something") {
    context("when something") {
      var a: SomeType

      beforeEachTest { 
        a = someNewMutableObject
      }

      it("should do something") {
        assertTrue(a.something()) // variable a not initialized
      }
    }
  }
```

How would one get around this problem? What could i assign to the variable to get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [lateinit](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables) modifier on the variable that will be initialised before use.

```
  describe("something") {
    context("when something") {

      lateinit var a: SomeType

      beforeEachTest { 
        a = someNewMutableObject
      }

      it("should do something") {
        assertTrue(a.something()) // variable a is okay to use here
      }
    }
  }
```

PS. `lateinit` local variables are available from Kotlin 1.2 only

In Kotlin 1.1 you should just initialise it to a default value or null (make it a nullable type also).